# Best practice passing data to view model

Tags: events, publish-subscribe, aurelia, message-passing

I have a login view which lives in its own shell. Also I have adjusted the `HttpClient` to automatically redirect to the `login` shell if any http request returns an `unauthorized` state.

Additionally I'd like to show some textual info to the user on the login page, after he has been "forcefully" logged out. How can I pass the information (`logoutReason` in the code below) from `MyHttpClient` to the `login` shell/view model?

Here's some conceptual code:

`login.js`

```
// ...
export class Login {
    username = '';
    password = '';
    error = '';

    // ...

    login() {
        // ... login code ...
        this.aurelia.setRoot('app'); // Switch to main app shell after login succeeded...
    }

    // ...
}
```

`MyHttpClient.js`

```
// ...
export default class {
    // ...

    configure() {
        this.httpClient.configure(httpConfig => {
            httpConfig.withInterceptor({
                response(res) {
                    if (401 === res.status) {
                        this.aurelia.setRoot('login');
                        let logoutReason = res.serversLogoutReason;
                        // How should i pass the logoutReason to the login shell/view model?
                    }
                    return res;
                }
        }});
    };

    // ...
}
```

---

**Solution:**

I've chosen to take the "event" path as suggested in [bluevoodoo1's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769499/best-practice-passing-data-to-view-model#comment64914938_38769499) with some adjustments:

- `MyHttpClient` fires/publishes a new `HttpUnauthorized` event which holds the needed information (description text, etc.)
- `MyHttpClient` doesn't change the shell anymore since the concrete handling of the 401 shouldn't be his concern
- `login.js` subscribes to the `HttpUnauthorized` event, changes the shell & shows the desciption text...

I'm still open to any suggestions/improvement ideas to this solution since I'm not quite sure if this is the best way to go...

Comment: You could publish an event? https://github.com/aurelia/event-aggregator

Comment: Thanks for the input. See my edit in the original question...

Answer (score 0):

You could set a `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` value and then clear it after you have displayed it. What you are asking for is known as a flash message where it displays and then expires.

**Within your response interceptor add something like the following:**

```
sessionStorage.setItem('message-logoutReason', 'Session expired, please login again');
```

**And then in the attached method inside of your login viewmodel, check for the value and clear it, like this:**

```
attached() {
    this.error = sessionStorage.getItem('message-logoutReason');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('message-logoutReason');
}
```

**Then in your view you can display it:**

```
${error}
```

As Bluevoodoo1 points out, you could also use an event, but I personally try and avoid using events as much as possible, harder to test and debug when things go wrong.

Comment: I've already thought of this & the event solution but they somehow don't feel right to me and I thought that there's maybe some aurelia built-in mechanism to better cope with such a scenario. Also see my edit to the original question...